# PHP all dates between date x and date y

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two html input dates as following:

```
Date 1 <input class="input100" type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date in.. dd/mm/yyyy">
Date 2 <input class="input100" type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date in.. dd/mm/yyyy">
```

And I have this PHP code:

```
$gdate = strtotime($_REQUEST['date']);
$gdate = date('Y-m-d', $gdate);
```

I put the date in my database as `$gdate`, but how do I make it so that it puts all the dates between and with date 1 and date 2 automatically into the database with a certain limit so it won't be too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php#109846

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2012-08-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2012-08-05' );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
2012-08-01
2012-08-02
2012-08-03
2012-08-04
2012-08-05
```

Comment: Thanks that works great! Is there a way I can set a limit so my database won't crash if someone puts in a lot of dates?

Comment: I don't see how something like this could "crash" a database, though you might want to check the [difference between the dates](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) if you want to limit the size of the span for more practical reasons.

Comment: Let's say someone fills in the date 5-5-0000 and 5-5-10000, then there would be a lot of dates which could crash the database maybe.

Comment: Spin up a test and try it. You'll be surprised what it takes to overwhelm even a half-decent database these days.

Comment: I'm inserting it like this into the database `foreach($daterange as $date){
  $data = $date->format("Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
  echo $data;
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $stad (gnummer, beschikbare_data)
  VALUES ($query_klantnummer, $data)" or die(mysql_error()); 
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
  }` However, it returns random years that are not the right one without day/month into the database. But when I echo $data, it returns the right dates with month/day?

Answer (score 0):

This my helpful to you

```
function date_range($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'd/m/Y' ) {

    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);

    while( $current <= $last ) {

        $dates[] = date($output_format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }

    return $dates;
}
```